# Loop through fixed number of chars in text file

Tags: python, loops, file

Let's say that I have a `file.txt` with consecutive characters (no spaces nor newlines), like this:

```
ABCDHELOABCDFOOOABCD
```

And I want to loop through the file, iterating through fixed amounts of 4 characters, like this:

```
[ABCD, HELO, ABCD, FOOO, ABCD]
```

A regular loop won't do: how can I achieve this?

Comment: `HELLO` is not 4 character

Comment: Exactly why won't a "regular loop" work? And what are you considering a "regular loop"? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can read four characters from the file at a time, by using `TextIOWrapper.read`'s optional `size` parameter. Here I'm using Python 3.8's "walrus" operator, but it's not strictly required:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    while chunk := file.read(4):
        print(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've read the input of your file and converted the entire chunk into a single string called data, you could iterate over it like so:

```py
individual_strings = data[::4]
```

This gives you a list of strings as required which you can then loop over!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   content = f.read()
   splited_by_four_letters = [content[i:i+4] for i in range(len(content))]
   // do whatever you want with your data here
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop like this would work. Not very pythonic, but gets the job done

```
s = 'ABCDHELLOABCDFOOOABCD'
for i in range(0,len(s),3):
    print(s[i:i+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module which has [wrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.wrap) function. So one can accomplish tasks without loop this way:

```
import textwrap

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    chunked = textwrap.wrap(f.read(), 4)

# chunked -> ['ABCD', 'HELO', 'ABCD', 'FOOO', 'ABCD']
```